# How to display parent node and child node side by side with TreeSelect in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd, web-frontend

This is my code. I want to show the parent node tag and the child node tag side by side

```
   <Form.Item
          label="Organization"
          name="organization"
          hasFeedback
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please select an organization!",
            },
          ]}
        >
            <TreeSelect
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              listHeight={200}
              value={org}
              dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: "auto" }}
              treeData={organizations}
              placeholder="Select organization"
              treeDefaultExpandAll
              fieldNames={{ label: "title", value: "key" }}
              allowClear
              multiple
              onChange={handleChange}
              maxTagCount={maxTagsVisible}
              maxTagPlaceholder={
                selectedCount > 0 ? `+ ${selectedCount} selected` : ""
              }
            />
        </Form.Item>
```

and this is my handle change function

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
setOrg(value);};
```